# asp:Login control - prevent submitting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using control asp:Login(asp.net webforms) and before authentification I need to check field "user.MustChangePassword".If it's true I need to redirect user to another page:

```
protected void signInControl_LoggingIn(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs e)
{ 
    ...
    if (user.MustChangePassword)
    {
        e.Cancel = true; // prevent authentification
        Response.Redirect("/ChangePassword.aspx"); 
        return;
    }
    ...
}
```

But redirect doesn't work and page is only reloading. How i can fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

That page path doesn't look correct. Add a `~` like below considering that your page lies in root of the folder

```
Response.Redirect("~/ChangePassword.aspx");
```

Comment: the url is correct. Now I found, that after calling redirect method, page is reloading and in the address bar I can see something like 
http://...mypath/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F%255Fl...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the login control's `DestinationPageUrl` property instead.

E.g.

```
signInControl.DestinationPageUrl = "/ChangePassword.aspx";
```

Comment: user will be redirected to signInControl.DestinationPageUrl after succes atempt to login. But i need to redirect him on changePassword page BEFORE authentification

Comment: That doesn't seem correct. Even if a password is expired, it is still the correct entered password and you should let the authentication process go through (e.g remove your return statement and `e.Cancel = true;`).

After authentication, you can redirect your user to a password change page, how would you otherwise know which user to change password for?

Comment: I must prevent authentification, because he will get claims. After that he can type address of any page of my app  in address bar and get it without password changing. I dont need it.

"how would you otherwise know which user to change password for"
- i'm using GET parameter  ...ChangePassword.aspx?UserName=...

Answer (score 0):

[Login.LoggingIn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggingin(v=vs.110).aspx) event is raised before logging in. So, one thing I can think of is you have to give anonymous access to ChangePassword.aspx page in web.config.

```
<configuration>
  <location path="ChangePassword.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

If changing password requires login, then you place the redirect logic inside [Login.LoggedIn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.login.loggedin(v=vs.110).aspx) event.

Comment: its not aproblem, ChangePassword.aspx already have anonymous access

Comment: How did you authenticate? Could you show the entire code of `signInControl_LoggingIn` event?